# Unit Testing Quartz.net Execute()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

First off, I am new to Quartz.net and Moq.

I am trying to unit test Quartz.net Execute method using Moq. The Execute() is defined in the IJob interface. The Execute method needs an IJobExecutionContext to be passed to it.

I have created a new job class named RunItinerary that inherits from the IJob interface. Below is an example of what I have.

```
public class RunItinerary : IJob
{
   public RunItinerary()
   {
   }

   public RunItinerary(IBFDatabase db) : base(db)
   {
   }

   public override void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
   {
     // magic happens
   }
}
```

Below is an example of my unit test. I have been unsuccessful in all my attempts to run a simple unit test. Here is an example of a test I tried.

```
var mockIJobExecutionContext = new Mock<IJobExecutionContext>();
var runItinerary = new RunItinerary();
runItinerary.Execute(mockIJobExecutionContext.Object);
mockIJobExecutionContext.VerifyAll();
```

Below is the error: (the x's are to mask internal names)

```
Test method xx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxJobs.UnitTest.RunItineraryTest.Execute_Success threw exception: 
xx.common.Data.Exceptions.DatabaseConfigurationSectionNotFoundException: JobDatabase
at xx.common.Data.Abstract.xxDatabase..ctor(String configSectionName) in xxDatabase.cs: line 39
at xx.windows.Scheduler.Data.JobDatabase..ctor(String configSectionName) in JobDatabase.cs: line 24
at xx.windows.Scheduler.Data.JobDatabase..ctor() in JobDatabase.cs: line 20
at xx.windows.Scheduler.Jobs.BaseJob..ctor() in BaseJob.cs: line 45
at xx.windows.Scheduler.xxxJobs.RunItinerary..ctor() in RunItinerary.cs: line 31
at xx.windows.Scheduler.xxxJobs.UnitTest.RunItineraryTest.Execute_Success() in RunItineraryTest.cs:
line 177
```

I believe something that I am missing is in the mockIJobExecutionContext.Setup(x => x.???????), I just cannot figure out what it is that I need to do with the .Setup()

I have reviewed similar posted questions about unit testing this Execute() but there has not been a clear answer with sample code.

If someone can provide an answer can you please provide a sample unit test for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `RunItinerary` (the class you are testing) has a 'default' behaviour when it comes to its dependency on `IBFDatabase`, which seems to be to new up an instance of a concrete class `JobDatabase`. Because this is a unit test, the `JobDatabase` is failing presumably because of missing configuration (e.g. connection strings etc)

> xx.windows.Scheduler.Data.JobDatabase..ctor() in JobDatabase.cs: line 20

Fortunately, it would appear that you have an alternate `RunItinerary` constructor allowing you to provide the `IBFDatabase` dependency:

```
var mockJobExecutionContext = new Mock<IJobExecutionContext>();
var mockBFDatabase = new Mock<IBFDatabase>();
// You may need to do the minimal required Setups on `mockBFDatabase` here
var runItinerary = new RunItinerary(mockBFDatabase.Object); // i.e. use the other ctor

runItinerary.Execute(mockIJobExecutionContext.Object);

mockJobExecutionContext.Verify(x => x.SomeMethod(someParam), Times.Once);
mockBFDatabase.Verify(x => x.FetchSomeData(theIdIAmExpecting), Times.Once);
```

Although it is quite commonplace when retrofitting unit tests (and dependency injection) into legacy code to have 'fallbacks' which couple classes to their dependencies if no injected dependency is provided, I would recommend that you try remove these ASAP to eliminate the coupling to concrete dependencies and replace this with an IoC container managed strategy - this way you can be 100% sure that the code you are unit testing is indeed the real production code.